# Can I put my NSF fellowship on reserve in order to investigate leaving academia?

Tags: career-path, mathematics, funding, nsf

I'm currently a PhD student in mathematics at a well-ranked school. Unfortunately, after a few years of increasing frustration and self-doubt, I'm considering leaving academia and trying to start a different career.

I currently have an NSF graduate fellowship. As described in [the information guide for fellows](http://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2004/nsf04054/nsf04054.pdf#page=8), one's "status" with regards to the fellowship can be either

- **Tenure:** Tenure is the period of time during which Fellows utilize
  the fellowship to pursue an advanced degree in science,
  mathematics, or engineering...
- **Reserve:** With prior Foundation approval, Fellows may reserve any
  two years over the five-year period to use an alternative means
  of support, *or to engage in activities other than graduate study...* (emphasis mine)

(There are also options for medical or military deferral. The full description of Tenure and Reserve status are in the linked document.)

Does this mean I can request to reserve my fellowship for the 2015-2016 academic year, using that time "test the waters" on another career, such that if I decide to stay in – or rather, go back to – academia, I would still have my NSF fellowship?

Of course if I do something like this, I would want it to be with my advisor's approval, though I haven't brought up this specific idea with them yet. Let's assume they are okay with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There do not appear to be any reservations on the purpose for requesting a deferral in the linked guide. You need to tell them in advance of filing the "Declaration To Utilize, Reserve Or Terminate A Subsequent Year Of A 3-Year Graduate Fellowship Award" and get their approval, but I don't think that there are many reasons for them to deny it. You might want to have *something* lined up like an internship, other job, or visit to a foreign university rather than just saying that you're taking a year away from studying. Though, I wouldn't be surprised if the latter happens, too.

Edited to add: You need to start talking to your supervisor and eventually the NSF Program Officer in charge of your fellowship.